# How to redirect within a monad in Yesod?

Tags: facebook, haskell, redirect, monads, yesod

I'm currently using the [fb](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fb/0.9.6/doc/html/Facebook.html) package to write a Yesod app that takes data from Facebook. In my Handler, I've managed to get the first step of the authentication to work, but I need to redirect to the url that `getUserAccessTokenStep1` returns, which I've defined as `fbRedirUrl`. I'm having trouble with all the monad wrapping and type checking to make sure I can redirect to this url.

```
getAccessTokenR :: Handler RepHtml
getAccessTokenR = do
  withManager $ \manager -> do
    FB.runFacebookT creds manager $ do
      fbRedirUrl <- FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1 redirUrl []
      liftIO $ print fbRedirUrl
```

Comment: can't you just return the URL to the outer level (`Handler`) then use `redirect` immediately on that?

Comment: @ScottWest Care to elaborate a bit more on what you mean by returning it to the outer level? I thought about doing that, but not sure how to do it with monads and such

Comment: Not enough space here, I'll try to answer below (but I can't really test it :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like if you pass the redirect URL back out through those layers of managers/Facebook monad then you can just feed it. The redirected URL's type is `Text`, which has an instance of `RedirectUrl` typeclass, necessary for using the `redirect` function (as seen in the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-core/1.0.1/doc/html/Yesod-Handler.html#g:5)).

You *should* be able to make this work with something like:

```
getAccessTokenR :: Handler RepHtml
getAccessTokenR = do
  url <- withManager $ \manager ->
    FB.runFacebookT creds manager $
       FB.getUserAccessTokenStep1 redirUrl []
  redirect url
```

There's no real magic here, you basically have two high-level patterns going on, one is the "with" pattern, that will localize a resource's usage (in this case the `manager`) and the other is the "run" pattern, that is really the use of Monad transformers (don't worry too much about the details of that yet!).

So `withManager` gives you a manager to use, presumably it takes care of some setup and takedown of the manager. This is probably typed something like

```
withManager :: (Manager -> Handler a) -> Handler a
```

Within that you have the facebook runner, which will be typed as:

```
runFacebookT :: Credentials -> Manager -> FacebookT Auth Handler a -> Handler a
```

Which basically says that if you give it some credentials, the manager, and some Facebook specific computation (like getting the redirect URL) it can translate that into your Monad of choice (here we pick `Handler`, because that's what `withManager` wants). In your case the `a` type variable is the `Text` of the redirect URL.

Using this pair of `with` and `run` patterns, we get the result that the URL which was supplied in the deep down in there, bubbles up into our `Handler` monad. Then we just snag it out and give it to the `redirect` function!

Comment: Yup that did the trick! Thanks! Now to pore over the type checking and see what sort of magic you pulled.

Comment: No problem! I've added a bit more to the explanation, hopefully it makes a bit more sense why it actually works.

Comment: Another approach would be using `lift` from within the inner monad.